# Convert HTMLTableElement to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with id "div_test".
In that table I have row with class "myclass".

When i'm trying 
`$('#div_test')` **null** is returned.

When i'm trying 
`$('div_test')` **HTMLTableElement** is returned and i cannot use any jQuery functions.

When i'm trying 
`$('#div_test tr.myclass')` **null** is returned.

When i'm trying 
`$('div_test tr.myclass')` **null** is returned.

How can I get row with "myclass" using jQuery or how can I convert **HTMLTableElement** to **Jquery** object?

Comment: $('#div_test') will return your table, if it exists with that id and jQuery is loaded.

Comment: `$` is not jquery in your code. You likely have some legacy code that is defining `window.$` as a function that gets an element by id.

Comment: in your console, what does `$` return?

Comment: ^^^ What Kevin said is probably the answer, jQuery doesn't return `null` for selectors that does not match a DOM element, and the second one returning the native element is strange, and it seems you're not using jQuery, but something else entirely ?

Comment: Bingo $ returning ---  function (sId) { return document.getElementById(sId); }  so I will use jQuery();

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($('#div_test tr.myclass').html());
});
```

and

```
<style>td{border:1px solid black;}</style>
<table id="div_test"><tr><td>not is</td></tr><tr class="myclass"><td>IS</td></tr></table>
```

on page load produces:

[image]

Your code appears to be OK, so your jQuery probably is not loading or your element HTML is wrong somehow. Check your browser debugging - my preference is Firebug for FireFox, but Chrome has a robust debugger, too. IE has right click > Inspect Element, which is mediocre but does give an indication.